# SQL Performance issue when using CASE

Tags: sql, case, table-valued-parameters

I have a SP that returns quite a lot of data every second and is shown in a grid. I'm now trying to reduce bandwidth and thinking of returning only columns currently shown in my grid.

This is of course simplified and minimized but basically what I had was the following SP:

```
SELECT
[Animals].[AnimalID] AS [AnimalID],
[Animals].[name] AS [AnimalName],
[Foods].[DisplayName] AS [Food],
[Animals].[Age] AS [AnimalAge],
[Animals].[AmountOfFood] AS [AmountOfFood]
```

What I’m currently trying is to pass a TVP of the names of the fields (@fields) currently shown on the grid and returning only required fields as such:

```
SELECT
[Animals].[AnimalID] AS [AnimalID],
[Animals].[name] AS [AnimalName],
CASE 
    WHEN ('Food' in (select * from @fields)) 
    THEN [Foods].[DisplayName] 
END AS [Food],
CASE 
    WHEN ('AnimalAge' in (select * from @fields)) 
    THEN [Animals].[Age] 
END AS [AnimalAge],
CASE 
    WHEN ('AmountOfFood' in (select * from @fields)) 
    THEN [Animals].[AmountOfFood] 
END AS [AmountOfFood]
```

The problem I'm facing is that (as could be expected) my SP went from taking ~200 ms to taking ~1 sec

Is there any way to maybe rewrite this so that it doesn’t kill us?

My kingdom for a foreach!!!

Comment: Is the bandwith really the problem?

Comment: I would imagine that your three case statements are resulting in more execution time taken than you are saving by not returning the columns. Simply return all columns and decide whether to display them using logic in your application view.

Comment: As mentioned the example was simplified :), we have close to 100 fields and a few dozen users each, at any given time, would probably not be looking at more than 5-10 fields. If there is no other way we'll just return all fields or use a broker, just looking for the best solution :)

Comment: How are you running this query? PHP? Perhaps it could be worth it to stitch together the query in your other language (PHP), and save SQL for what it is good for? If you do it right, it will be protected against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can also do this with dynamic SQL.  Something like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = (select ', '+
                      (case when FieldName = 'Food' then 'Foods.DisplayName'
                            when FieldName = 'AnimalAge' then 'Animals.Age'
                         . . .
                       end)
               from @fields
               for xml path ('')
              );

select @sql = 'select [Animals].[AnimalID] AS [AnimalID], [Animals].[name] AS [AnimalName]'+@sql+RESTOFQUERY;

exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to convert the stored procedure into Table-Valued function, and make your grid select only required columns from it.

So your function would still select

```
SELECT
[Animals].[AnimalID] AS [AnimalID],
[Animals].[name] AS [AnimalName],
[Foods].[DisplayName] AS [Food],
[Animals].[Age] AS [AnimalAge],
[Animals].[AmountOfFood] AS [AmountOfFood]
```

If the client only selected for example `select * AnimalID, Age from myfunction(..)`, only these columns would be transferred to the client.

Comment: This works beautifully, however with the number of fields I have performance is affected :/